# If current bounds lie in others (many) bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps v3.
I want to know **IF current map bounds lies in a sum of all previous bounds (all points of current bounds are covered by other bounds)** (if not, I will load markers for current bounds via ajax)

Let say, I have an array of previous viewport bounds, that I do so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle',function() {
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
   boundsArray.push(bounds);
});
```

The algorithm to check that I invented by now is a hard one and it is the following:

1) Generate all edge points (lan/lon) of current bounds with some **$step** (0.0001?) and put them in "pointsArray".

2) Iterate over pointsArray, and check if current point exists in at least one previous bounds:

> From LatLngBounds doc: contains(latLng:LatLng)    boolean Returns true if the given
>   lat/lng is in this bounds.

so, something like:

```
if (boundsArray[y].contains(pointsArray[i]) {
```

and if contains, then remove that point from pointsArray

3) Finally, after all iterations, if the pointsArray is empty — it means all points of current bounds are inside another/s bounds and function returns true...

There are in my opinion 2 disadvantages of my algorithm:
1) it is not 100% precise (depends on $step)
2) and that is worse, it my cause performance drop on a client, checking so many points by all bounds... as javascipt is implemented on users PC.

So, if the any more precise & easy, faster solution for my problem? maybe using another math approaches, google geometry library & so on? How to do that correctly?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - please tell us about X. Is it that you have so many markers you need to prune the ones not in the viewport?

Comment: For each current viewport - I must load markers data from server, but I do not want to do that IF current viewport is inside another view (for what I already loaded markers) OR if current view is covered by earlier views (so the markers is already loaded and I should not do that again...)

Comment: So it _is_ an optimization/performance issue. Are you sure you need this? Can't you just request all markers in the viewport, remove the ones outside the viewport and skip rendering duplicates? That seems like the most straightforward.

Comment: I will do that if there is no easy way to do that I want to do... I also afraid if markers count per view will be huge (1000+) all that rendering stuff also may be slow. I want to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, I get that. Is it then safe to assume that the viewport only changes a little bit? Like, you move 100km west, rather than _random_ movement? Because then I see use in your proposed solution.

Comment: The view can be changed in any way, slow or rapidly, just the way user drags, zooms...

Comment: Hmm, have you consider using the MarkerManager? http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the bounds array when it becomes too big. Then you can start again. It's much easier then to compare the bounds.

Comment: I afraid, that even checking points for 2 bounds may be slow, because points count will be relatively big (more then 1000 I suppose)